# return element in list refering to index

Tags: python, string, list, numpy

Assuming I have a list of words:

```
l = ['example', 'to', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']
```

And I get an index i, let's say `10`.

What I need is to return the element in `l` that contains the i-th char,

So in the example of 10, as the 10-th element (zero-based) is the `l` from the word `list` - what I need to return is the word `list`.

Iv'e been trying to think of a simple way to do this, and I didn't find something elegant.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: How would you do it by hand?

Comment: Loop over the list. If the length of the current word is less than `i`, return that word. Otherwise, subtract its length from `i` and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import count

l = ['example', 'to', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']

c = count()
print(next(s for s in l for _, i in zip(s, c) if i == 10))
```

Prints:

```
list
```

---

Another solution (using [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/bisect.html) module):

```
from bisect import bisect
from itertools import accumulate

l = ['example', 'to', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']

lengths = [*accumulate(map(len, l))]
print(l[bisect(lengths, 10)])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
i = 10

for word in l:
    i -= len(word)
    if i < 0:
        break

# the value of word is 'list'
```

and if you want it in a function

```
def at_index(l, i):
    for word in l:
        i -= len(word)
        if i < 0:
            return word
    return None
```

Comment: Use print(word) before break, otherwise if i > total length, word will be always the last word in the list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use next and the walrus operator to keep track of your counts too. Basically keep subtracting the length of every string from `i` and then once i is less than 0, that's the string:

```
l = ['example', 'to', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']
i = 10

result = next(s for s in l if (i:= i-len(s)) < 0)
```

Result:

```
'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
ind = 10
ll = 0
for item in l:
    ll+=len(item)
    if ll>=ind+1:
        print(item)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeating each word for each of its letters, and then just picking the i-th word:

```
[s for s in l for _ in s][i]
```

Or more efficiently with a generator and `itertools.islice`:

```
next(islice((s for s in l for _ in s), i, None))
```

Answer (score -1):

I got that wrong ...  the @
-----Keeo it simple ...

```
In [1]: l = ['example', 'to', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']

In [2]: s = "".join(l)

In [3]: s
Out[3]: 'exampletoalistofwords'

In [4]: s[10]
Out[4]: 'l'
```

I believe, even in 1 line of code it is still readable (pythonic)

```
 "".join( ['example', 'to', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words'])[10]
```

Comment: the output should be the word not the character. It should return 'list'