# Get index of letter in word in list based on index

Tags: python, string, list, numpy, python-itertools

Assuming I have a list of words:

```
l = ['example', 'to', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']
```

And I get an index i, let's say `10`.

What I need is to return the index of the letter inside the word in `l` that contains the i-th char,

So in the example of 10, as the 10-th element (zero-based) is the `l` from the word `list` - what I need to return is 0, as `l` is the first letter in the word.

For i=17, for example, the output will be `1`, as 17 refers to the letter `o` in `words` - and the index of `o` in `words` is 1.

Iv'e been trying to think of a simple way to do this, and I didn't find something elegant.

Any help will be appreciated!

I asked a similar question and got good answers here:

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63366725/return-element-in-list-refering-to-index)

But couldn't find a good way to modify the answer to what I need here.

Comment: 17 refers to `w` of  `words` for me

Comment: @Clément - start counting in 0

Comment: Can't you just slightly modify an answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63366725/13008439)? Why don't I see any attempt from you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return element in list refering to index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63366725/return-element-in-list-refering-to-index)

Comment: @Clément - no - please look at my edit.

Comment: @superbrain - I edited the question. The questions are similar, and the examples are similar, but what I need is totally different. Anyway I didn't find a good way to transform the answer to what I need here.

Comment: It's not totally different at all, and it's trivial to adjust the answer you accepted there.

Comment: @superbrain  Why did you log in? To tell people their question is not good? If you know the answer and it is trivial for you please post it and I'll happily accept it. If not - please move on to "help" other people...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution you accepted in your previous question (finding the word):

```
c = count()
print(next(s for s in l for _, i in zip(s, c) if i == 10))
```

Trivial modification to solve your new question (finding the index in the word):

```
c = count()
print(next(j for s in l for j, i in zip(range(len(s)), c) if i == 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be much simpler than the accepted one (`l` is your lust of words, `i` is the index of the letter):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

result = next((idx for idx, x in enumerate(l) if alphabet[i] in x), None)
```

You can use any alphabet (in this case I used `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`). Also, it's important to set a default value for the `next` function, otherwise you could have an exception.

Answer (score -1):

```
l = ['example', 'to', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words']
index = 10

fl = [(c[1], c[0], w[1], w[0]) for w in enumerate(l) for c in enumerate(w[1])]

print('char = ' + fl[index][0] +
        ', index in word = ' + str(fl[index][1]) +
        ', word = ' + fl[index][2])

# char = l, index in word = 0, word = list
```

If you need only the index in the word :

```
fl2 = [c[0] for w in enumerate(l) for c in enumerate(w[1])]
print('index in word = ' + str(fl2[index]))

# index in word = 0
```